# How to make a global variable have a different value with each html page?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game (like 4 pics 1 word) and it involves having an answer variable. There will be a button that onclick will run a function that checks the user's answer if it matches the value of this variable. There will be one puzzle per page and each puzzle/page will have a different value for answer variable. This variable must have its value set when the page loads. I looked it up and I don't see anything that would help me and I have no idea how I would do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move your global variable so it isn't global across pages. Make it so it's global to the page (not pages).

Comment: Do you want to use the same script for every page?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here? It seems like you just have to put a different variable inside each HTML page.

Comment: I want to use the same script for every page but with that variable different and without prompting the user (the page loads with that variable different.

Answer (score 4):

You might need either `localStorage` or use `Cookies` for this case. If you are targeting modern browsers, you are free to use `localStorage`, which is a concept of HTML5.

When you are using the `click` event, use this:

```
localStorage.setItem('scores', [scores-array]);
```

And then when you are loading the page, try this:

```
localStorage.getItem('scores');
```

To learn more about `localStorage`, use this:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [Dive Into HTML5 - LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

The other option of **Cookies**, depends on your browser's privacy settings. Many browsers (not many) would probably disable cookies, but you can use it as an alternate. You have limited data type storage (only strings), which can be initiated using:

```
document.cookie="scores=" + score_data;
```

And retrieving them using:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
getCookie(scores);
```